# Return current data when a user would abort R

Tags: r

Would it be possible to return the data from the current iteration when a user would abort R?

Something like:

```
if (user.aborts == TRUE) { return(data) }
```

This would be really useful since the input for this procedure is only data. It could then be broken up, and continued afterwards.

Comment: What do you mean by abort? An interrupt? If so, look into `tryCatch`, which can accept an interrupt handler.

Comment: `C-c C-c` in Emacs is linked to a function `(comint-interrupt-subjob)` So I believe an "interrupt" is the term indeed?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible, if what you mean is manually stopping the process, e.g.

```
myfun <- function(x){
  on.exit(return(x))
  for(i in 1:5){
    x <- x + 1
    Sys.sleep(1)
  }
}

x <- myfun(1) # Stopping before it finishes
x
[1] 4
```

Comment: Very nice.  Just commenting to mention that `on.exit` will work like this if a function exits due to an error or even just in the natural course of its statements.    Also that you could build a gambling machine by running an infinite loop around `x<-runif(1)` :-)